# OkHttp ignores GET paramters

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp v4.2.0 to implement HTTP calls for my app.

So this is the login API, tested with Postman. It works fine.
[image]

My code:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LoginTask loginTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginTask = new LoginTask("moch.sanusi", "admin");
        loginTask.execute();
    }

    class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private String userid, password;
        private String responseServer;

        public LoginTask(String userid, String password){
            this.userid = userid;
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            responseServer = "";
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

            Request httpRequest = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://xxx.yyy.zzz/login.php")
                    .addHeader("userid", userid)
                    .addHeader("password", password)
                    .method("GET", null)
                    .build();

            Response httpResponse = null;

            try {
                httpResponse = httpClient.newCall(httpRequest).execute();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                if (httpResponse != null){
                    responseServer = httpResponse.body().string();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            return responseServer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            System.out.println(">>> "+s);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (loginTask != null) loginTask.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

The output of my code is:

> {"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters email or password is
>   missing!"}

Which is true if you call the API without the parameters:
[image]

I'm confused. What's missing here?

Comment: Use OkAuthenticator for auth.

Comment: This is off-topic, but sending credentials as query parameter is a pretty terrible idea, as they will be visible to in the server logs and probably other places. See [this article](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/) for additional info.

Comment: @kenny_k Thank for the link. Yeah this is just a quick hack. But definitely will improve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are sending header values and not query parameters to the server. In Postman you are using the proper query parameters so everything works fine. You can use the [HttpUrl](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-http-url/) builder provided by OkHttp to build the URL properly.

Ex:

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
.scheme("https")
.host("xxx.yyy.zzz")
.addPathSegment("login.php")
.addQueryParameter("userid", userid)
.addQueryParameter("password", password)
.build();
```

Then pass that `url` object to the `url()` method on your `Request.Builder`

**Note:** Using query parameters to pass credentials is not a great solution from a security perspective. Although this solution will solve your problem I would change the login implementation from the server side to be more secure.

Comment: Hmm weird. I think they way I implemented POST in my question worked. Let me check my old codes again... Anyway, HttpUrl works though :)

Answer (score 0):

Your sending a **JSON** value to the server.where as your PHP script expects **key value pair**

**So here is the solution**

**Replace**

```
LoginTask loginTask;
loginTask = new LoginTask("moch.sanusi", "admin");
```

With

```
  HashMap<String, String> loginTask= new HashMap<String, String>();

  /*Adding elements to HashMap*/
  loginTask.put(userid, "moch.sanusi");
  loginTask.put(password, "admin");
```

And **remove both addheader** (userid,password) as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This will not solve the problem. The issue is that the request should send the credentials as query params (which, btw is a terrible idea from the security perspective), instead of header params.